# Cannot import a local js file in html page

Tags: javascript, html, import

I am getting an error when I try and import a js file in my html. I've even put the html in the same folder as the data.js. I'm using Chrome

```
GET file:///C:/Users/dm/Documents/timezone/data.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

My script is below

```
<html>
<script src="data.js"></script> 
<!-- other stuff here -->
</html>
```

Comment: add type="text/javascript" and add /before data.js and try

Comment: some browsers won't let you load js from local filesm which one is causing you trouble?

Comment: google chrome is the troublemaker

Comment: Are you sure your file ending actually is .js? It is not just you who have named the file "data.js" when it actually is "data.js.txt"